# Editing /etc/paths does not change $PATH

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I have to add my mysql bin to the $PATH in OSX 10.9.3.
While searching on google I found the following [guide](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.VlRFsnuFPnQ) which tells me to add an extra line in the /etc/paths file.

I tried this but my $PATH does not get updated. I tried restarting terminal, loging out and ever rebooting but nothing seems to help.

This is what my /etc/paths looks like:

```
~ Pantera$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/bin
```

but when echoing $PATH those last 2 lines do not get added.

```
~ Pantera$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

What step did I miss?

-- edit --

as asked:

```
~ Pantera$ /usr/libexec/path_helper
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.9-osx10.9-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/sbin"; export PATH;
```

So it seems the paths are included but still terminal gives me `command not found` when trying the `mysql` command.

content of /etc/profile

```
~ Pantera$ cat /etc/profile
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml
export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml
```

content of ~/.bash_profile

```
~ Pantera$ cat ~/.bash_profile
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/ruby193/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export MSF_DATABASE_CONFIG=/usr/local/share/metasploit-framework/config/database.yml
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `/usr/libexec/path_helper`? Please edit that into the question. Also, better tell us what is your shell. (By the way, the "correct" way to add program-specific paths is to put a file in `/etc/paths.d`, but this doesn't explain the problem at hand.)

Comment: @4ae1e1 tried the command and updated my question. thanks

Comment: As you can see `/usr/libexec/path_helper` is doing its job right, but you have to `eval` its output to have it take effect. Are you using bash? Can you post the content of your `/etc/profile`? And are you running a login shell? I don't have a Mavericks system at hand, but looking at El Capitan, `/usr/libexec/path_helper` is not run and sourced when the shell is not a login shell.

Comment: Yes I am using bash. AFAIK Terminal runs as a login shell by default so I assume I am running a login shell (correct me if I am wrong, read this somewhere on SO)

Comment: Simple test: `bash -lc 'echo $PATH'`. What do you get?

Comment: The same as the normal `echo $path`

Comment: Okay, then you must be overriding the path somewhere. Post `~/.bash_profile` please.

Comment: updated the question. Already lots of thanks for the help

Comment: Well, you're hard coding `PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile`, multiple times for that matter... If you want to add a directory to your `PATH`, do `PATH=/path/to/dir:$PATH`.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more detailed about that i should put as /path/to/dir:$PATH? As I understand i have to put the dir where $PATH is located? Where is that? I have googled it but can't find anything specific

Comment: I'm not here to give you a tutorial. There are plenty around the web. Here's the first result when you Google "linux path": http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html. In a glance it looks okay, and mentions the idiom I had above.

Comment: And here's the third result, from U&L: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path.